# Problems with 2 functions in onBlur

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am having the next trouble, I have the next textinput

```
               <TextInput
                  style={styles.inputs}
                  placeholder="Nombre"
                  placeholderTextColor={theme.SECONDARY_TEXT_COLOR}
                  underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                  autoCorrect={false}
                  autoCompleteType="off"
                  autoCapitalize="characters"
                  onBlur={(() => setvName(values.fName), handleBlur('fName'))}
                  value={values.fName}
                />
```

as you can see i have 2 functions on onblur, the thing is that it works great when i dont have handleBlur('fName') on it, but i need both of them for my formik validation, how can i make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use like this to call multiple function.

```
onBlur={() => {
      setvName(values.fName); 
      handleBlur('fName');
     }}
```

Comment: @user10625391 if answer is helpful for you please mark accept/vote for this. Happy coding!

Comment: sure, in 5 minutes, this thing have a timer for that